# ffmpeg/libav skips frames in case of network disconnection

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, transcoding

I have remote m3u8 playlist with ts files. I'm trying to read it with `av_read_frame`. For some reason, in case of quick reconnection to the network (I used `sudo ifconfig myInterface down && sudo ifconfig myInterface up`) I have missed frames: it skips all data from the current ts file and jumps to the next ts in playlist. Do we have any `AVDictionary` options or something else to prevent this behavior?